# AngularJS directive within ng-if won't run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I have a custom directive `myDirective` that performs a task on an element.

I have this directive in an `ng-if` block

```
<div ng-if="condition">
    <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

Something like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hGnvv/ only the `ng-if` condition turns to true after my `$http` requests are loaded.

The directive is probably compiled during runtime, but never linked, so the code never runs. If I replace the `ng-if` by `ng-show` the directive works fine.

Any solutions?

**Edit**: I can't use `ng-show` because I have 130 directives within the form. 20 directives run anyway, and the other run according to my object type.

- `ng-if="type == 1"` then load these elements
- `ng-if="type == 2"` then load other elements etc.

If I change the `ng-if` to `ng-show`, the form takes 8s to load instead of 1s.

Comment: You already have a solution. Replace ng-if with ng-show

Comment: I can't do that, I have like 130 directives on a single form. If I replace the ng-if with ng-show, all this code that has to run turns the form much slower (8s instead of ~1s).

Comment: Use ng-show if possible. Ng-if removes element from DOM, so there is no way for angular to compile it.

Comment: @AlexArvanitidis - 130 directives - what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue wasn't that the directive wasn't running, but that the `$watch` functions that I had inside it didn't run at all. I didn't manage to understand the exact reason of the issue, because the same directive works fine outside `ng-if`.

Anyway changed my `$watch` to -> `$watchCollection` and it works fine now, since it sees all updates to the objects I'm $watching.

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-if` condition is initially false, therefore the element does not exist in the DOM and the directive was not linked.

When the ng-if condition later becomes `true`, the link callback should fire correctly, as seen in these examples:

Setting `ng-if` to true when button is clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/q05gret0/

Setting `ng-if` to true after `$http` request is loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/fhu8ky62/1/

If you're not getting this behaviour, the problem might be with an inherited scope; check the `ng-if` is monitoring the same scope variable that your request is updating. [This article](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/parent-child-controller-communication) has a few points on parent/child scope variable shadowing and other limitations.

Comment: I want to run the code when the ng-if condition becomes true. The issue is that when it becomes true, the link of the directive does not run.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was not the issue. I managed to find it, posting it in another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

for example if your model is like `$scope.item = true` and you use it like `ng-if="item"` you should change your model to `$scope.myvalue = {}` and use like this : `ng-if="myvalue.item"` , at all I mean you should use object property for `ng-if` not a simple value